# Char array having integer values In Java

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I am using JAVA for coding.
My Aim is to put Location of array into that position of array and it has to be a char array 
My current Code:-

```
    char arr[]=new char [16];
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=i+1+'0';
    }
```

or

```
    char arr[]=new char [16];
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=i+1;
    }
```

Is not working for java and am getting error "Cannot convert int to char".
I have tried finding out about it but i only received solution for c++ and that code dosent work in Java giving the same error.

Comment: Thank You everyone,  arr[i] = (char)(i + 1);   works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast the value you are trying to put into the array as a `char`. The reason for this is that `char` is a 16 bit number and `int` is 32 bits

```
   char arr[]=new char [16];
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(char) (i+1+'0');
    }
```

or

```
    char arr[]=new char [16];
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        arr[i]= (char)(i+1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast it explicitly to a char.

```
arr[i] = (char)i + 1;
```

or maybe

```
arr[i] = (char)((char)i + 1);
```

If the output of char + char gives an int (because of whatever reason you can think of).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to assign an integer value to a char!
Cast it to char first.